# How can I change the default SSL certificate for local development in ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, security, .net-core, ssl-certificate

How would I be able to configure my own certificate as the "default" used by Kestrel when running local ASP.NET core apps on Linux?

I know that I can run the `dotnet dev-certs https` command to generate a new development certificate, but that will generate a new self-signed certificate.  I don't want to have to trust this certificate - I already have my own local CA for development and would like to sign a cert for use by ASP.NET core.

I also know that you can configure the cert Kestrel uses within my app code (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/), but I don't believe this should be part of the application. It's my personal preference to use my own CA-signed cert locally, and I don't want to force other developers to manage their own certificates if they're happy trusting the auto-generated cert.

I have tried dropping a certificate into the local "My" certificate store where the self-signed development cert gets created (`~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/`), but it doesn't get used - I get the error that happens when you don't have a cert at all:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
> Unable to start Kestrel.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

Is it possible to configure my own certificate, or am I forced to use the one generated by dotnet core?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer:

It turns out ASP.NET core looks for specific extensions on the default certificate it uses when configuring Kestrel.  If you want a certificate to be picked up, it needs the extension "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1" set, and the raw byte value of this extension should be >= 2 ([from reading the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c4d043dc86e52e8b83f8c0ef3500f2985f90c23c/src/Shared/CertificateGeneration/CertificateManager.cs#L83)).

Dropping a certificate with this extension (and some other basic extensions) into the "My" store allows the cert to be used by default.

### Long answer:

(Read the short answer first)

You can't use an existing certificate.  Because ASP.NET core requires specific extensions on the certificate it uses, you will need to create a new certificate to be used.  However, you still *can* use a certificate signed by a CA, as long as you generate your request correctly.

Assuming use of openssl, you can facilitate this through a configuration file when generating your certificate request:

**asp_config.conf**

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = aspnet

[ dn ]
CN = localhost

[ aspnet ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = critical, serverAuth
subjectAltName = critical, DNS:localhost
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1 = DER:02
```

You can then run the openssl command to generate a signing request using this config:

```
openssl req -new -config asp_config.conf -keyout local_asp_dev.key -out local_asp_dev.csr -nodes
```

After generating the request, sign it with your CA.

```
openssl x509 -req -in local_asp_dev.csr -CA /path/to/CA.pem -CAkey /path/to/CA.key -CAcreateserial -out local_asp_dev.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extensions aspnet -extfile asp_config.conf
```

> You need to specify the extensions to grant to the certificate using the `-extensions` option.  This options looks at the specified configuration section in the referenced file.

Once signed, you need to pack your certificate into a pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in local_asp_dev.crt -inkey local_asp_dev.key -export -out local_asp_dev.pfx
```

After packing your certificate, simply drop it into your "My" store - ASP.NET will pick it up and use it to serve your HTTPS endpoints.  (You may need to remove any other development certificates that were automatically created in this store).

```
mv local_asp_dev.pfx ~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/
```

Note that the location of this store on Linux is considered an internal implementation detail and is subject to change.  It's also entirely possible that future versions of ASP.NET core will require different extension values.

**This solution was developed and tested against ASP.NET Core 3.1**

Additional References:

- "My" store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#the-my-store
- openssl config: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html
- Extension granting when signing with a CA: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28965

Answer (score 3):

You can designate any certificate as the default using environment variables. This is what works on my machine:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Location LocalMachine
setx ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Store My
setx ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Subject example.com
```

On Linux you can have something like this:

```
export ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=path_to_pem
export ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__KeyPath=path_to_key
export ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password_to_key_file
```

## Explanation

The settings for ASP.Net Core applications can be provided using multiple configuration sources:

> - Settings files, such as appsettings.json
> - Environment variables
> - Azure Key Vault
> - Azure App Configuration
> - Command-line arguments
> - Custom providers, installed or created
> - Directory files
> - In-memory .NET objects

Search MSDN for Configuration in ASP.NET Core for more details.

By default, Kestrel configuration is loaded from the Kestrel section of the settings file. Here is a configuration example of the default certificate.

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The certificate can be specified as:

> - Path and Password to load .pfx files.
> - Path, KeyPath and Password to load .pem/.crt and .key files.
> - Subject and Store to load from the certificate store.

Comment: Have you found that the OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1` is necessary in the certificates? Or have you been able to bypass that?

Comment: @duct_tape_coder : I have found that OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1` is NOT necessary in the certificate. I did not have to bypass it. By using the method described I am able to use any certificate which is valid for server authentication. A few minutes ago I ran my test app with a certificate generated by letsencrypt.org. I verified that it did not have OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1`.

Comment: I found the same as well when using the appsettings.json file: the OID is not required and I was able to use my existing "IIS Express Development Certificate" also for Kestrel.  
`"Kestrel": {  
      "Certificates": {  
        "Default": {  
          "Subject": "localhost",  
          "Store": "My",  
          "Location": "LocalMachine"  
        }  
      }  
    }`

Comment: if anyone is considering using these commands, keep in mind it's a global configuration and it will affect all of your projects that you try to run with Kestrel on your PC.. I have ran into this problem and was not able revert Kestrel to its original state.

Comment: @EmreBener, did that occur even when you cleared out the ENV vars?

Comment: @Bayu , the commands provided are intended for setting the environment variables once for the development machine. setx on Windows sets global "system" environment variable. export works on Linux and I normally put it inside ~/.profile. Of course, you can overwrite it in your local script in both cases, but it is a topic for a separate discussion.

Comment: the problem have gone away. turns out all you need to do is deleting `location` and `store` variables, and setting `subject` variable back to `localhost` to revert.