# Kestrel and self signed certificate. The desktop application in the intranet

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, kestrel-http-server

I want to secure connection in the intranet environment between local WebApi and desktop application. I cannot use official certificates, I will not use specific domain names, it will not be used online.

I've created self signed certificate using OpenSSL and use it like: [Kestrel and self signed certificate error during startup application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858074/kestrel-and-self-signed-certificate-error-during-startup-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The Kestrel is not playing nicely and still not use certificate I'm giving, instead use default one. [How can I change the default SSL certificate for local development in ASP.NET core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947072/how-can-i-change-the-default-ssl-certificate-for-local-development-in-asp-net-co?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To mitigate, you need to fake default certificate which Kestrel is waiting for. I'm not sure why is that? Even I'm adding my certificate to trusted root on local machine, Kestrel doesn't bother and is waiting for "special one".

How you deal with such an issue? What option I have if I want to secure connection and use self signed certificate?

Here is a sample how I run kestrel with certificate '.pfx' file.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseSerilog()
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
          webBuilder.UseKestrel(webOptions =>
          {
            var port = 8000;
            webOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions =>
              {
                listenOptions.UseHttps(GetCertificatePath(), GetCertificatePassword());
              });
          });
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show your own code, instead of pointing to other posts.

Comment: @LexLi I've added snippet how I load certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this question on github/aspnetcore and get the answer.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36204#event-5293269898

The issues was because I had Kestrel settings in appsettings.json as well as in Program.cs `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>...` and at the end only those from appsettings.json are taken, which unfortunately does not contains certificate details.