# Certificate from Local Store in ASP.NET Windows Service Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, .net-5, asp.net5

Based on this documentation I am trying to use a certificate that is installed on the local machine in my net5 ASP.NET implementation that runs as Windows service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#listenoptionsusehttps

Specifically, I am referring to this config snippet:

```
  "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
    "Certificate": {
      "Subject": "<subject; required>",
      "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
      "Location": "<location; defaults to CurrentUser>",
      "AllowInvalid": "<true or false; defaults to false>"
    }
```

I struggled a lot, since this documentation lacks the description of all values of the parameters.

So I ended up with this:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:7000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:7001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "value-of-CN-parameter-of-subject-field",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work:

```
[15:53:59 FTL] Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: The requested certificate value-of-CN-parameter-of-subject-field could not be found in LocalMachine/My with AllowInvalid setting: False.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, Boolean allowInvalid)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(CertificateConfig certInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I checked the following points that were mentioned to be needed:

1. the certificate has a private key
2. the certificate has the enhanced key usages `Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)` and `Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)`

From the `Subject` field of the certificate, I tried all variants:

- value from `CN` parameter only
- `CN=value`
- complete subject in CSV form

Specifying a certificate by `*.pfx` file works without a problem. So what is going wrong with accessing the locally installed certificates?

Note: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65958649/2477582 mentions the `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1` extension, but according to the referenced source code, this is for development certificates only.

I am trying to set up a production environment instead.

Comment: What account is the service running under? Your certificate might not be in the correct store?

Comment: I tried it from the Windows service where it is running as Local System and directly from Visual Studio where it is running with my own user. When addressing the `Location` as `LocalMachine`, shouldn't this be user independent then? (sorry if this question is dumb, but this was my assumption...!?)

Comment: @Nicolas I am curious, does your certificate have a private key? This might cause the issue, when it's missing.
And did you double-check your Location and Store values?

Comment: @WΩLLE-ˈvɔlə yes, the certificate has a private key. Though I multi-checked the `Location` and `Store` values, I am still not 100% sure about them - because they aren't documented anywhere (at least I didn't found anything). The values I chose above were from other user examples. So, the certificate is in the "Personal" store of the "Local Computer" ... I found "My" and "LocalMachine" in other users examples....

Answer (score 0):

My application is different, but this will probably help you. I needed to run a graphql service through Kestrel using a custom DNS name AND custom certificate through a Visual Studio launch profile. This is what worked for me.

A couple of key points:

- Kestrel uses [`CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/CertificateLoader.cs) under the covers. This API will **NOT** locate a certificate that does not meet the following qualifications: (it will give no warning or feedback, just simply return null. oof)
- The certificate must have a private key in the Windows Certificate Store. The only way I know of to do this is to import the certificate in `pkcs12` format. (`.pfx` file extension) You will see a special icon for certificates that contain their private key.
- [image]
- You will also see this message when viewing a certificate that includes it's private key in the store.
- [image]
- [`CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/CertificateLoader.cs) docs mentions it searches a certificates "Subject", which isn't a thing or standard terminology as far as I know. Its actually searching the distinguished name of the certificate, which is comprised of a bunch of individual key/value pairs. Setting the `description` or `commonName` field under the distinguished name to something 100% unique to your specific certificate will do the trick.

1. So we can get a custom DNS names on local.

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 local.whatever.io
127.0.0.1 local.admin.whatever.io
```

2. Setup our custom DNS name in the launch profile and the port we want to use in kestrel

**Properties/launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Whatever.GraphQL": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "graphql",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://local.whatever.io:36305"
    }
}
```

3. Tell Kestrel how to find the certificate we want in the Windows Certificate Store

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        // if you don't import your .pfx into the Windows Certificate Store you could just load it from disk here. the major 3 browsers will likely NOT trust your certificate, which is why importing it into the LocalMachine\Root store is recommended.
        //"Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        //"Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
        "Subject": "Whatever Localhost Certificate V1",
        "Store": "Root",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "AllowInvalid": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Certificate generation/configuration is stupidly complex along with deciphering the "standards" around them, so skipping most of that complexity here. I created a powershell script for localhost development that generates a Root Certificate Authority, imports it into the Windows Certificate Store, generates a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for localhost development using the below text as an example, then generates and signs the CSR using the Root Certificate Authority to produce these files: `localhost.crt`, `localhost.key`, and `localhost.pfx`. The `.pfx` can then be imported into Windows Certificate Store , and then utilized by Kestrel. In docker you can utilize the `.crt` & `.key` for [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) or [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) or whatever proxying service you've setup if that is also needed.

You can use `openssl` to generate certificates using this configuration.

> You'll need to already have generated a root certificate authority cert (rootCA.crt) and private key (rootCA.key), and imported it into the certificate store.

```
// create certificate signing request (.csr) and .key based on config
oppenssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out localhost.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout localhost.key -config localhost.conf -extensions v3_req 
// sign the .csr using the root CA cert to generate localhost.crt
oppenssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 3600 -sha256 -extfile localhost.conf -extensions v3_req
// append full certificate chain to the .crt for all browsers/proxies/all-the-things
rootCA.crt >> localhost.crt
// convert to .pfx format so we have the cert and key in one format
oppenssl pkcs12 -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt -export -out localhost.pfx
// import .pfx into store. you now have the cert and key in the certificate store that Kestrel will find
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "localhost.pfx" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $standardPassword -AsPlainText -Force)
```

*localhost.conf*

```
[req]
default_bits                        = 4096
distinguished_name                  = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions                      = v3_req
prompt                              = no
serial                              = 12345678
authorityKeyIdentifier              = keyid, issuer

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                         = US
stateOrProvinceName                 = TX
localityName                        = Austin
organizationName                    = Whatever LLC
description                         = Whatever Localhost Certificate V1
name                                = Whatever Localhost Certificate V1
commonName                          = Whatever Localhost Certificate V1
businessCategory                    = Ecommerce
owner                               = Indiana Jones
emailAddress                        = certs@whatever.com
serialNumber                        = 12345678
streetAddress                       = 1234 Wherever Lane
postalCode                          = 78758
jurisdictionLocalityName            = Austin
jurisdictionStateOrProvinceName     = TX
jurisdictionCountryName             = US
    
[v3_req]
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical, digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = serverAuth, clientAuth, codeSigning, timeStamping, emailProtection
subjectAltName          = @alt_names
    
[alt_names]
# add as many wildcards or non-wildcards as you want. just make sure to always increment the number
# note: every sub-level of a domain requires a wildcard
DNS.1 = *.whatever.io
DNS.2 = *.admin.whatever.io
DNS.3 = *.funtimes.whatever.io
# adding the current machine's full list of IPV4 & IPV6 ips, as well as the usual loopback adapters
IP.1 = 172.19.16.1
IP.2 = 172.20.224.1
IP.3 = 172.24.80.1
IP.4 = 172.30.64.1
IP.5 = 172.30.80.1
IP.6 = 192.168.56.1
IP.7 = 192.168.88.59
IP.8 = 0.0.0.0
IP.9 = 127.0.0.1
IP.10 = ::
IP.11 = ::1
IP.12 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:177B:3CA1:44E3:0000
IP.13 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:53AF:9CDB:A86D:0000
IP.14 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:592B:C5D5:30A0:0000
IP.15 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:86D2:F50A:E0C8:0000
IP.16 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:C08A:C61F:10DF:0000
IP.17 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:D2C2:A734:A360:0000
IP.18 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:EC80:EB1F:C21D:0000
```